# Should IMPORTED_IMPLIB be set if IMPORTED_IMPLIB_<CONFIG> is set?

Tags: c++, cmake

I noticed that the config file of the [fmt library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) sets the target properties `IMPORTED_IMPLIB_RELEASE` and `IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE`, while `IMPORTED_IMPLIB` and `IMPORTED_LOCATION` are not set.

```
fmt::fmt BINARY_DIR = C:/Build/test_install/fmt
fmt::fmt CXX_MODULE_HEADER_UNIT_SETS =
fmt::fmt CXX_MODULE_SETS =
fmt::fmt HEADER_SETS =
fmt::fmt IMPORTED = TRUE
fmt::fmt IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS = RELEASE
fmt::fmt IMPORTED_GLOBAL = FALSE
fmt::fmt IMPORTED_IMPLIB_RELEASE = C:/Build/win_x86_64_release/lib/fmt.lib
fmt::fmt IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE = C:/Build/win_x86_64_release/bin/fmt.dll
fmt::fmt INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS = FMT_SHARED
fmt::fmt INTERFACE_COMPILE_FEATURES = cxx_std_11
fmt::fmt INTERFACE_CXX_MODULE_HEADER_UNIT_SETS =
fmt::fmt INTERFACE_CXX_MODULE_SETS =
fmt::fmt INTERFACE_HEADER_SETS =
fmt::fmt INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES = C:/Build/win_x86_64_release/include
fmt::fmt LOCATION = C:/Build/win_x86_64_release/bin/fmt.dll
fmt::fmt LOCATION_DEBUG = C:/Build/win_x86_64_release/bin/fmt.dll
fmt::fmt LOCATION_RELEASE = C:/Build/win_x86_64_release/bin/fmt.dll
fmt::fmt NAME = fmt::fmt
fmt::fmt POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE = True
fmt::fmt SOURCE_DIR = C:/Source/cmake/package/build/libs/test/fmt
fmt::fmt SYSTEM = ON
fmt::fmt TYPE = SHARED_LIBRARY
```

The target properties `LOCATION` and `LOCATION_<CONFIG>` are generally set.

Should the target properties `IMPORTED_IMPLIB` and `IMPORTED_LOCATION` always be set to one of the corresponding `IMPORTED_IMPLIB_<CONFIG>` and `IMPORTED_LOCATION_<CONFIG>` values?

I'm a little worried that without putting that, problems will arise when I build a debug build against a release fmt lib. (E.g. with [`TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS).)

**Background:** I am currently implementing some test projects to validate my library installations. I want to have all library config files in a way that enables `TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS` to collect all required DLL files. Also a debug build of my own projects should work with the release builds of the libraries. This is useful for debugging stuff which requires a heavy processing in external libraries. (Currently I have two separate library filesystem structures for debug and release.)

I test `IMPORTED_IMPLIB` and `IMPORTED_LOCATION` in my validation, but some libraries like `fmt` are only setting the `<CONFIG>` specific versions.

Comment: "... problems will arise when I build a debug build against a release fmt lib." - If `TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS` doesn't check appropriate `IMPORTED_LOCATION_<CONFIG>` property, then it looks like a bug in the implementation of that generator expression. Otherwise I see no problems with the config file you show. BTW, that config file is **generated** by CMake. So, whether a config file is wrong or TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS behaves wrongly - these both CMake bugs. Could you provide **more details** about **actual problems** you have faced?

Comment: Okay, sounds reasonable, thank you! Can you make the comment an answer so I can accept it? [Not all users read comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294792/4821621) ;-)

Comment: Actually, I don't find useful the question in its current state. You have a generated file, which **works at least in normal case** (when you just link with the `fmt::fmt` and don't use TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS). And you ask whether that file is correct, as you are concerning about .. some **unspecified** code being not working. So, what a reason to answer the question, as neither you nor anybody else may **verify correctness** of that answer?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I added background information about the question. I also can confirm that  TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS does work cross Debug/Release.

Comment: "I also can confirm that TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS does work cross Debug/Release." - So, everything works correctly with the given config file. In that case, what is the reason to ask about correctness of that file? I mean, than anyone can point to arbitrary location in the existing code and ask about its correctness. But the value of such questions will be questionable when one talk about Question/Answer library like Stack Overflow is.

Comment: Well, the title of your post - "CMake: Should IMPORTED_IMPLIB be set if IMPORTED_IMPLIB_<CONFIG> is set?" - seems to be good question by itself, as it asks about CMake specification in general. But current body of your question shifts that general aspects into very specific problems (about TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS) ... which are not actual problems. And that is really confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should `IMPORTED_IMPLIB` be set if `IMPORTED_IMPLIB_<CONFIG>` is set?

Property `IMPORTED_IMPLIB` is just a fallback for configurations, for which property `IMPORTED_IMPLIB_<CONFIG>` is not set.

That is, it is perfectly correct to specify properties `IMPORTED_IMPLIB_<CONFIG>` (for one or more configurations) but **omit** `IMPORTED_IMPLIB` property. This would mean that imported location is defined only for specific configurations.

Note, that in case of the IMPORTED target its configuration may differ from the configuration of the whole project. That difference may be resulted from setting [MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_<CONFIG>](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_CONFIG.html) properties for that target.